# MYSQL full text search not working properly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If i am search a term 'rexx', then the result will show all the entries similar with the search term. For example:

```
Search Term: rexx
Records: 
 1. Candyrexx
 2. Paidrexx
 3. PayPal Rexx
 4. Rexio
 5. to Rexx
 6. Rexxio 

Result: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6
```

I will try with the query `SELECT * FROM user WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+rexx' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` but i get the entries(3, 5, 6) as result. The record 1 and 2 is missing in the result.

Comment: As the documentation clearly explains, the wildcard character only goes at the end of the word, not the beginning.

Comment: Why don't use `LIKE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  The wildcard is only supported at the end of the word.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) specifies:

> *
>
> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
>   the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words
>   match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.

MySQL full text search does not (directly) support the functionality that you are looking for.  You *can* use `LIKE` instead, but that usually performs much worse.